# Am i misunderstanding $\nabla f*\vec{u}$?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Im currently studying multivariable calculus and im left puzzled by the correction to one of the exercise.

Exercise1: Find the unit vector in the direction of which $f(x,y) = 4+x^2−3y^2$ decreases most rapidly at the point (1, 1) and find the rate of change at this point in the direction you find.

My understanding is that to solve this kind of problem you must find $\nabla f$ to find the direction of steepest ascent AND then find $\vec{u}$.

So I started by taking the partial derivative at (1,1) to find the directional derivative. Hence you get $\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix} 2x \\ -6y \end{bmatrix}$ and you plug the point (1,1) in. Then in accordance with $\nabla f . \vec{u}$ i thought i could do $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -6 \end{bmatrix}$*$\sqrt{40}$ to find the rate of change.

This is wrong since my professor finds -$\sqrt{40}$, what am I missing here?

Comment: You gave the direction of maximal INCREASE.  The professor wanted descent, not ascent.

Comment: Right so if you want the gradient descent you would multiply this by -1 ?

Comment: Right.  The theorem says the direction of the gradient gives steepest increase, the opposite direction gives most decrease.  And when you put the opposite vector into the dot product formula, the extra minus sign is apparent.

Comment: @Randall thank you for your answer ! Thank you for taking the time.